# Entity Framework executing stored procedure does not return values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, dbcontext

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the variable `works` returns 743 rows, but the variable `notworks` returns none?

As far as I can see they are doing the same thing.

I cannot publish the stored procedure, but I don't think that is the issue here as I am able to get a result set from the first variable.

I tried using a SQL trace - which I am new to - and could not see anything that helped me solve this.

```
var TretSpefParameter = new SqlParameter("TretSpef", "101");
var SexParameter = new SqlParameter("Sex", 1);
var SDiagParameter = new SqlParameter("SDiag", "*");

var works = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<sp_RefData_Predictive>("sp_RefData_Predictive @TretSpef = '101', @Sex = 1, @SDiag = '*'").ToListAsync();

var notWorks = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<sp_RefData_Predictive>("sp_RefData_Predictive @TretSpef, @Sex, @SDiag", TretSpefParameter, SexParameter, SDiagParameter).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Have a look on it : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Post the stored procedure declaration.  You are using named parameters in the first call, but positional parameters in the second one, which could cause a parameter assignment mismatch.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

I had to change:

```
@TretSpef, @Sex, @SDiag
```

to

```
@TretSpef=@TretSpef, @Sex=@Sex, @SDiag=@SDiag


var notWorks = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<sp_RefData_Predictive>("sp_RefData_Predictive @TretSpef=@TretSpef, @Sex=@Sex, @SDiag=@SDiag", TretSpefParameter, SexParameter, SDiagParameter).ToListAsync();
```